# Play animation upon collision with enemy

Tags: python, pygame

so I have loaded the images into pygame:

```
Explosion = [pygame.image.load('Explosion1.png'), pygame.image.load('Explosion2.png'), pygame.image.load('Explosion3.png'), pygame.image.load('Explosion4.png'), pygame.image.load('Explosion5.png'), pygame.image.load('Explosion6.png'), pygame.image.load('Explosion7.png'), pygame.image.load('Explosion8.png'), pygame.image.load('Explosion9.png'), pygame.image.load('Explosion10.png')]
```

and I would like, when the bullet, which is a separate class, makes a collision with the missile, it plays this animation at the position where both the bullet and the enemy collide, I'm not sure how I go around doing this?

Collision Script (In the main loop):

```
hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemies, bullets, True, True)
```

Bullet Class:

```
class Bullet (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self, x, y):
        super (Bullet, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Bullet.png").convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255,255,255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedx = bullet_speed
    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx

        if self.rect.left > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            self.kill()
```

Enemy Class:

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Missiles.png").convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255,255,255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(Enemy_SPEED_Min, Enemy_SPEED_Max)



    def update(self):
        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
```

all of the code is here https://pastebin.com/CG2C6Bkc if you need it!

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not destroy the enemies, when it collides with an bullet. Iterate through the enemies and which are returned in `hits` and start the explosion animation instead of killing the enemies:

<s>`hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemies, bullets, True, True)`</s>

```py
hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(enemies, bullets, False, True)
for enemy in hits:
    enemy.start_animation()
```

Add the attributes `animation_count`, `animation_frames` and `animation` to th class `Enemy`. When the explosion animation is started then `animation` is set `True`. `animation_frames` controls the speed of the animation. If the animation is started, then the enemy stops to move and the `Explosion` image is shown instead of the enemy. After the last image of the animation is shown, the enemy is killed:

```py
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.image.load("Missiles.png").convert()
        self.surf.set_colorkey((255,255,255), RLEACCEL)
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(
            center=(
                random.randint(SCREEN_WIDTH + 20, SCREEN_WIDTH + 100),
                random.randint(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT),
            )
        )
        self.speed = random.randint(Enemy_SPEED_Min, Enemy_SPEED_Max)

        self.animation_count = 0
        self.animation_frames = 10
        self.animation = False

    def start_animation(self):
        self.animation = True

    def update(self):

        if self.animation:
            image_index = self.animation_count // self.animation_frames
            self.animation_count += 1

            if image_index < len(Explosion):
                self.surf = Explosion[image_index]
                self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)

            else:
                self.kill()

        self.rect.move_ip(-self.speed, 0)
        if self.rect.right < 0:
            self.kill()
```

Comment: It worked but it says "TypeError: 'Enemy' object is not callable".

Comment: elif event.type == ADDENEMY:
                new_enemy = Enemy()
                enemies.add(new_enemy)
                all_sprites.add(new_enemy)

Comment: I changed it to, ```for enemy, in hits:``` and it says "TypeError: start_animation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Comment: @WilliamWolseley-Charles Of course it has to be `enemy.start_animation()` rather than  `Enemy.start_animation()`, too. Note `enemy` is not the class `Enemy`, it is an instance object of the class. `enemy` it is just a variable name. You can use any name (e.g. `hugo`, `foo`): `for hugo in hits:` `hugo.start_animation()`

Comment: It worked! It looks great, you might end up coding the whole game at this rate!

Answer (score 1):

Well i dont want to do it for you, But i will say one way you could do it, then you can go and try to do it, and if you run into a problem/error, you can update the question and we can help you.

I would create another class called `Explosion` and and give it the images, when when you draw it, draw the first image, then change to the second, then draw that one, then change...

Then after it finishes, destroy the object.

So, create the class, create a spritegroup, when the bullet collides, create a new instance of the class, giving it the x and y co ordinates of the collision, update it every frame, and it will draw all the images then destroy itself

also, an easier way to get all of your images instead of typing them all out is

```
Explosion_imgs = [pygame.image.load("explosion" + str(x) + ".png") for x in range(1,11,1)]
```